# Error opening connection to SQL CE file on test machine

Tags: c#, uac, sql-server-ce

I'm testing my application on a non-administrator windows 7 account. The application is installed into program files. This includes the .sdf file I need to read from. I've got the connection string marked as read only and set the temp path to my documents. This is the error that it spits out when I try to do `connection.Open()`

> Internal error: Cannot open the shared
>   memory region

I've got the connection string defined in app.config, but I'm modifying it before I start using the connection. This part is in app.config `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf;Password=password;`

And then I modify it like so:

```
    connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString +
 ";Mode=Read Only; Temp Path=" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
```

This works on my developer machine (obviously) since its running from outside of a read-only directory. But even when I manually mark the .sdf file as read-only it still works, and successfully creates the temporary db file in the correct folder. However, on the test machine everything is located in a read-only program files folder, and it doesn't work.

The main goal of this problem is trying to make sure my program doesn't have to be ran as an administrator, and I would like to keep from moving the main copy of the db file from outside of the installation directory.

Let me know if I need to explain anything else. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you will require Administrator level priviledges to access a SQL-CE database in the Program Files folder (or any other protected folder). Why do you need this installed in to Program Files? If you install the database to ProgramData (i.e., Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) you will not require admin priviledes, and is arguably the proper location?

Comment: It was a requirement for the project to keep all the files located together. I'll look into doing it that way to since that will probably work. Also, does the fact that the DB is read-only not matter?

Comment: One would expect that read-only would be fine... Windows treats the Program Files, Windows and other System folders as "protected" and thus is very picky about the type of file access. The documentation around the issue is very poor; thus difficult to provide concrete facts about why your are seeing this behavior. Out of curiosity, have you tried a Temp Path that is set to System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()?

Comment: Installing the db in the program data folder worked. I guess I shouldn't be too surprised at that though. The Path.GetTempPath() didn't work however. It spat out the same error as I've been having all along

Comment: Yeah, ProgramData is the expected place to store that type of information; I would definitely recomend installing the DB there. As for the TEMP, figured it was worth the long shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a sql ce database too and had the same problems. my solution was to create the database in a subfolder in *Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData*. If only one user will use it you can create it in *Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData*. But here you don't need admin rights.

Another point is your connection string in your app.config. If you'll modify it in your program like me, it must be located in such a 'non-admin-right-needed' folder too. I have a static app.config in my app-folder in program files, but a second one with the connection string in *Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData* (this is 'username\AppData\Local' in Win7). And I protect my connectionstring with *DataProtectionConfigurationProvider* encryption, so no one can read the data base password.

This is how you can map your second app.config to your app:

```
string ConfigPathString = @"{0}\MyApp\MyApp.config";
string ConfigPath = String.Format( ConfigPathString, System.Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData ) );

ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = ConfigPath;
Configuration Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration( fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None );

string myConnectionString = ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringKey"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing. I put mine in CommmonApplicationData since I wanted 1 install for multiple users. It sure stinks that I couldn't do it the other way, but this way is just as good. Thanks for reaffirming my solution.

Comment: I think this is a very common issue regarding sql ce in win systems with UAC. you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Like Calgary already mentioned in his comments you can't really open the file directly in the programs folder due to the restrictions of Windows 7 to non-admins. But due to the fact that you don't want to write anything into it, why don't you simply copy at startup the file into `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`?

When your program starts up simply copy the file out of the programs folder into a proper location, use it as you like and delete it on application exit. So you don't leave any fragments (except the application would crash).

Just to be sure for the last scenario, you could add an additional delete operation to the setup deinstallation routine. So if the application will be removed and it crashed at the last start the setup will remove the trash, leaving the machine as before the installation of the software.

Comment: I was actually thinking about doing this as the solution, but it turns out that the project wouldn't suffer as much from having something outside of program files as it would if we had to copy the database on start-up